# attempt to concatenate nil with string Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm very confused. I'm trying to make it so that if you hold E with Roblox's "ProximityPrompt", you will get a GUI on your screen with some text.
Everything works except that the text won't appear. I also am not writing a string on the client script. There is a variable for it on the server script that gets passed over. But I keep seeing this error in the output:

> Players.ford200000.PlayerGui.BuyGui.Frame.TextInput.Text:2: attempt to concatenate nil with string  -  Client -

Here is what I'm doing in my script

```
local sp = script.Parent
sp.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
    local name = sp.Name
    local ss = game.ServerStorage
    local item = ss.Hats:FindFirstChild(name)
    local price = item.Price
    game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopClickEvent:FireClient(player)
    game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopInfoEvent:FireClient(player)
end)
```

And in the local script that listens for ShopInfoEvent

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopInfoEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(player, price, item)
    script.Parent.Text = "Would you like to buy this ".. item.Name .." for ".. price.Value .."?"
end)
```

Please help, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: `local sp = script.Parent
sp.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(player)
 local name = sp.Name
 local ss = game.ServerStorage
 local item = ss.Hats:FindFirstChild(name)
 local price = item.Price
 game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopClickEvent:FireClient(player)
 game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopInfoEvent:FireClient(player)
end)
`

Server script

Comment: `game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopInfoEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(player, price, item)
 script.Parent.Text = "Would you like to buy this ".. item.Name .." for ".. price.Value .."?"
end) 


`

Client script

Comment: @ford200000 please not that posting code in comments is not a good as you cannot format it properly. Instead, edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is telling you that the object you are trying to add to a string is undefined.
This could be `item.Name` or `price.Value` is undefined and causing this string construction to fail.

Looking at how you are defining `item` and `price` shows that both of these values are undefined in your LocalScript's callback. When you call a [RemoteEvent's](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent) [FireClient function](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/RemoteEvent/FireClient), the first argument tells the engine who to send the event to, and all the other arguments get passed in as the arguments of the callback. Currently, you aren't passing in any arguments at all.

So to fix your problem, you need to pass in the right arguments from the Script:

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopInfoEvent:FireClient(player, price, item)
```

and parse them properly in your LocalScript :

```
game.ReplicatedStorage.ShopInfoEvent.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(price, item)
    script.Parent.Text = "Would you like to buy this ".. item.Name .." for ".. tostring(price.Value) .."?"
end)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kylaaa, I tried what you said but got a new error in the output.

| Players.ford200000.PlayerGui.BuyGui.Frame.TextInput.Text:2: attempt to index nil with 'Name'  -  Client |

It says that the 'Name' is nil.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! I can only pass the one word through the script so I had to make the varibale 'price' pice.value. And I had to make a new varible for 'name' and then everything worked! Thank you so much, I can finally continue working on other things in that game!

Comment: Would you like to see the game in progress?

Comment: Send me a link on Roblox

Answer (score 2):

> Players.ford200000.PlayerGui.BuyGui.Frame.TextInput.Text:2: attempt to
> concatenate nil with string - Client -

tells you everything you need to know.

You're trying to concatenate nil with string. That means you're using the string concatenation operator `..` with a nil operand in line 2

So let's look into line 2

```
script.Parent.Text = "Would you like to buy this ".. item.Name .." for ".. tostring(price.Value) .."?"
```

`"Would you like to buy this "`, `" for "` and `"?"` are obviously strings. That leaves us with `item.Name` and `tostring(price.Value)`.

If `price.Value` were `nil`, `tostring` would turn it into `"nil"`. So this cannot be the cause of this particular error message.

That leaves us with `item.Name`. If item were `nil` we would see an error for indexing a nil value instead. So that tells us that whatever `item` is, it is not what we expected to be. A table with an element for key "Name".

At this moment you know that something is wrong with the parameters of your function. So you (hopefully again) refer to the manual and compare that with the way you use those event functions.

Comment: Oh, and sorry Piglet. Your message didn't help me much. I hope you understand.

Comment: @ford200000 I just added this to Kylaaa's spoon-fed solution so you can actually learn something. actually I told you how to solve problems like this on your own and how to make sense of this error message. I'm not interested in reputation and green hooks. so next time please try to make sense of an answer rather than telling the author that it doesn't help. Understanding error messages and tracking their cause down efficiently is vital for any programmer

Comment: Thank you for telling me this, I'm still growing as a programmer.

Comment: Thanks for adding this excellent explanation Piglet. I'll try to explain the problem and reasoning steps better in the future so my answers aren't just spoon feeding solutions. Do you have any other suggestions on how I can improve my answers?

Comment: @Kylaaa just add a little why to the how. I also like to refer to manuals a lot. Getting information from manuals is a crucial skill so I try to show people that they could have found a solution by readig manuals or with simple debug prints